# Jquery time how to make a progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var count = 0;
    var timer = $.timer(
        function() {
            count++;
            $('.count').html(count);
        },
        1000,
        true
    );  
</script>
```

How can i make a progressbar with timer ?
Example every second add to div with

```
    <div style="background:#000;width:$.timer%;"><< here</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery UI plugin. ( with timer )

https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

```
<script>
  var v = 0;
  var upProgress = function() {
    v++;
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: v
    });
    setTimeout( upProgress , 1000 ); 
 };

 $(function() {
  setTimeout( upProgress , 1000 );   
 });

</script>
</head>

<body> 
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PS. Try exploring the new progress element ;)

```js
$("progress").animate({v:1}, {
  duration: 5000,
  step: function(v){
     this.value = v
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress min="0" max="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery:

HTML

```
<div id="progressbar">0%</div>
```

CSS

```
#progressbar {
    width: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

JS

```
function progressBar() {
  var progress = 1, timer, percent;
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
  var loop = function loop (progress) {
    if (progress === 11) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    } else {
      percent = progress * 10;
      bar.style.width = percent + 'px';
      bar.textContent = percent + '%';
      timer = setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++progress);
    }
  }
  loop(progress);
}

progressBar();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7t6ozspz/24/)